# How to remove 'bloat' from a compiled shared object?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-errors

I have a gcc C application which compiles to a shared object using the `-fpic` 
option. The intent is to create a 'executable' which allows running the code **anywhere** in the memory.This is how a sample C program is compiled.

```
./armeb-eabi-gcc -march=armv5t -mbig-endian -nostdlib  -fpic   -c  main.c
```

main.c

```
 int main(){
    void (*UART)() = 0x594323 | 1;
    UART("Hello");
}
```

The problem is the compiled executable has 'bloat' where i am only looking for machine code and no symbols. I was unable to extract the exact portions from `objcopy` and `objdump` which did absolutely nothing. The file size is around 948 bytes which is insane for such simple program.

Here is a snippet of the 'portion' of the file i am looking for.
[image: hex dump of main.o]

(The exact highlighted parts could be skewed)

---

Running

```
objcopy -I elf32-big -O binary main.o test.bin
```

gives a 64 byte file which for some odd reason moves part of the string to the top of the file which makes tools like ghidra and ida unable to disassemble properly. 
[image: hex dump of the sanitized file]
[image]

Hopefully it can be seen that the reference to "Hello" is incorrect.

Comment: I haven't used pic on ARM but shouldn't you use the "arm-none-eabi" version of the compiler instead? Otherwise I'm not sure what overhead the compiler will dump in your executable, regardless of `-nostdlib`.

Comment: Well arm-none-eabi fails to compile for big endian.

Comment: What exactly did you try with `objdump`? How did it fail? It is quite capable concerning binaries.

Comment: `objcopy -I elf32-big -O binary main.o test.bin` gives a 64 byte file but the string part of the code is copied to the top of the file which is strange on its own sense and tools like ghidra are unable to properly link the string to the function.